# Laravel - check if other people are using my API and who

Tags: laravel, http

I have an API and I'm not sure if other services are using it too. I don't want other people to use my server resources and I would like to check that.

1. Assuming I have a method in a controller, how I can check who accesses this method where the request is not from my domain?
2. How I can allow connections only from my website/app and refuse from any other source?

Comment: Do you use any kind of auth?

Comment: Nope @Samsquanch, I only know that I use `Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each request has a `Host` header you can use that to know which domain is using your service.

if you want to only allow your domain to access the service then edit the `CORS` settings. I'm assuming you are using [barryvdh package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

in `config/cors.php`

change the value of

```
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
```

to your domain instead of * wildcard

Answer (score 0):

You can also use extended library (like so: https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard) to add API key to your app so only those who know it can make requests to API.